# Safari not rendering CSS based on media queries, works in chrome though

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, mobile-safari

Update: Link to actual file: https://fikers.github.io/projects/entrepreneur21/index.html

I use some JavaScript to create table rows from some external data and then add them to my page. For different screen sizes, I move some elements around. For Chrome, everything works fine but for some reason, for Safari, two things seems to be happening:

1) If I load the page at a large width and then make it smaller, it messes up the elements. Basically, instead of using new CSS that should be applied at smaller widths, it's moving around those elements as if I didn't have the media queries.

Meanwhile, if the screen is initially loaded below a certain width, the page is messed up similar to the above situation, as if I had loaded it with a large with and tried to make it smaller and everything got messed up.

2) As I said, I'm using JavaScript at the start to create table rows and add them to the page dynamically. To make the page look good for smaller sizes, I actually combined 2 of the table row data items into one line (less than 50% width each with inline-block to appear on the same line). I also made the table heading disappear on smaller widths. As you can see from picture 4, if you go from a smaller width to a larger width, the a href elements within the links column, which get moved around at a smaller width, do not snap back into place if you increase the width - this is only on Safari (web and mobile.)

How can I basically force Safari to check what the page width is and rerender it or whatever the best solution here is.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks on different screens with different widths:

[image: Safari initial load with a small width]

[image: The same page loaded in Chrome with a small width, this is how it should display]

[image: How it looks on Safari and Chrome properly for large widths if you start with a large width initially]

[image: On Safari, if you start with a small width and make it larger.]

Safari initial load with a small width

The same page loaded in Chrome with a small width, this is how it should display

How it looks on Safari and Chrome properly for large widths if you start with a large width initially

On Safari, if you start with a small width and make it larger.

Comment: You're going to need to post some code. Either in a plunk (plnkr.co) or a fiddle (jsfiddle.net). Without seeing the code, it's impossible debug.

Comment: @couzzi fair enough, ill do that right now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=PFivU3G2yN I added the HTML/CSS/JS as well as I could. unfortunately, the JS script isn't running so the elements aren't showing up.. However, I'd added a link to the actual file hosted on my github account.

Comment: This has nothing to do with building the elements in `javascript`. Copy/paste your output markup and you'll have the same issue. Most probably, adding `display:block` to `.tableRow` in the narrow `@media` will help. Can't test on Safari at the moment. However, you should not use `<table>` elements here. This doesn't seem like tabular data. It looks more like a list of items. You know when it's tabular data? When you have a total underneath, or when you want to sort by values in a certain column.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu You are a god among men! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I simply added the display: block line and it made everyything work exactly as I initially expected / wanted / as it does on other browsers.

Comment: Glad I could help. Since most of the question is based on a wrong assumption, it's hard to believe it will help future visitors. I know you invested time in it, but you might want to consider deleting it. Of course, it's all up to you. Happy coding! :: }<(((*> ::)

Comment: Try to use a setTimeout of 10 ms to apply styles after a browser repaint. I often do it to solve rendering problems.